# Moving an event log source is not having an effect

Tags: windows-10, powershell, event-log, powershell-3.0

I'm having an issue that to be clear I'll describe in steps:

1. I created an event source called `Foo` in the event log called `Application` using the following powershell command:
   `New-EventLog -source Foo -LogName "Application"`
2. I could successfully log to the event log using that source.
3. Afterwards, I decided to remove the source and re-create it in a different event log:

```
Remove-Eventlog -Source "Foo"
New-EventLog -source "Foo" -LogName "My App Log"
```

**The problem I'm having is** that then when I run `Write-EventLog -LogName "My App Log" -Source "Foo" -EventID 0 -EntryType Information -Message "Some message."` the entry is logged to `Application` instead of to `My App Log`

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Your code sample in item 1 (`New-EventLog -source SerilogTest -LogName "Axioma Services"` doesn't match your description. Can you clarify?